# Exception: "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.setDataElements(IntegerInterleavedRaster.java:301)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.setRGB(BufferedImage.java:988)
    at MyManager.imageMan.fazerNova(imageMan.java:354)
    at MyManager.imageMan.main(imageMan.java:472)
```

I need a some help please.

```
  public static BufferedImage fazerNova(int abc[],BufferedImage img) {

    BufferedImage teste1 = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int k = 0; k < abc.length; k++) {
        int w1 = abc[k] % img.getWidth();
        int h1 = (int) Math.floor(abc[k] / img.getWidth());
        teste1.setRGB(w1, h1, 0xffffff);
    }
    return teste1;
}
```

Comment: Well what diagnostics have you tried? What are the values of `h1` and `w1` which are failing? What is `abc[k]`?

Comment: The line is this:

teste1.setRGB(w1, h1, 0xffffff);

Comment: w1 and h1 are the width and height of my image.

Comment: I use %, / and math.floor, because i want round certains values by excess, and anothers by default

Comment: @FCoelho: No, `w1` and `h1` are values based on `abc[k]` - look at how they're initialized. But we don't know what the values of `abc[k]` are meant to be, so we have no idea what the values of `h1` and `w1` actually are. I suggest you add logging in the loop - ideally of `abc[k]`, `w1` and `h1`. I suspect at that point, everything will become clear. But there's not a lot we can do to help you without any more information.

Comment: For example. in abc[5] it's stored the value "488".
I want calculate what is the position in width an height of this position.
Using my code, i have the position in x and y of my point.
example-> width of my image is 240: 488%240=8, 8 it's position in x, and (int) Math.floor(488 / 240) it's y positon=2..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot link to a small (in bytes) image that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look a the `BufferedImage` [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), it is clearly written:

> An ArrayOutOfBoundsException may be thrown if the coordinates are not
>   in bounds. However, explicit bounds checking is not guaranteed.

So you did exceed the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Thank you..
I already solved my problem.

I mistook a variable.